# Queries running in a loop

Tags: sql, mysql

I have stepped into a serious problem.

I am working in a db where one user is child to a previously registered user.

And that child will be having another two child users.

This goes to n levels

So i tried to find out the super most parent of the nth level user the problem arised

Now i am using query running in a loop to find out this, but i know its weird and my database server will hang once the levels starts to increase.

somebody please show me some light.

can stored procedures be used for this?

Comment: can you provide a table structure? just the fields that are important are required to answser.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` BIGINT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`point` BIGINT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`left` BIGINT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`right` BIGINT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`referel` BIGINT( 11 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ; this is the table structure it is an MLM software

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer here : http://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/arborescence/ (checknig for english document).

It means you will have to design your table again but some search queries will be very faster (it avoids recursivity).

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch from the db **in one query** only the first level of every user,

get all the results into big array,

in your server side languages you can run an algorithm, that find the most parent,

**don't use sql queries to do that**.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have hierarchical queries so this can't be done efficiently via SQL. You must calculate data for this query during write not during read.

Just add a column "most parent" to your table.  Or you can add a sting value where you can store a path to current record. For example

```
id parent path
1  null   null
2  1      /1/
3  2      /1/2/
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i need to find out all the users above the current registered user, not the only parent one. even if i am trying to find out all the users above i will have to run the queries in a loop. or am i wrong?

Comment: If you add "path" to your table in format "1,2,3,...", you can select path from your user, and then execute only one dynamic SQL command like "select * from users where id in (path)"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example that requires a single non recursive db call to generate an employee hierarchy. You should easily be able to adapt this to your model.

Full script can be found here : http://pastie.org/1266734

Hope it helps :)

**Example MySQL calls**

```
call employees_hier(1);

call employees_hier(3);
```

**Example PHP script**

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db", 3306);

$result = $conn->query(sprintf("call employees_hier(%d)", 1));

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 echo sprintf("#%s %s -> #%s %s<br/>", $row["emp_id"],$row["emp_name"], 
    $row["boss_emp_id"], $row["boss_name"]);
}
$result->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

**MySQL Script**

```
drop table if exists employees;
create table employees
(
emp_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) not null,
boss_id smallint unsigned null,
key (boss_id)
)
engine = innodb;

insert into employees (name, boss_id) values
('f00',null), 
  ('ali later',1), 
  ('megan fox',1), 
      ('jessica alba',3), 
      ('eva longoria',3), 
         ('keira knightley',5), 
            ('liv tyler',6), 
            ('sophie marceau',6);


drop procedure if exists employees_hier;

delimiter #

create procedure employees_hier
(
in p_emp_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default(0);
declare v_dpth smallint unsigned default(0);

create temporary table hier(
 boss_id smallint unsigned, 
 emp_id smallint unsigned, 
 depth smallint unsigned
)engine = memory;

insert into hier select boss_id, emp_id, v_dpth from employees where emp_id = p_emp_id;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

create temporary table emps engine=memory select * from hier;

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from employees e inner join hier on e.boss_id = hier.emp_id and hier.depth = v_dpth) then

        insert into hier select e.boss_id, e.emp_id, v_dpth + 1 
            from employees e inner join emps on e.boss_id = emps.emp_id and emps.depth = v_dpth;

        set v_dpth = v_dpth + 1;            

        truncate table emps;
        insert into emps select * from hier where depth = v_dpth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

select 
 e.emp_id,
 e.name as emp_name,
 p.emp_id as boss_emp_id,
 p.name as boss_name,
 hier.depth
from 
 hier
inner join employees e on hier.emp_id = e.emp_id
left outer join employees p on hier.boss_id = p.emp_id;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists emps;

end #

delimiter ;


call employees_hier(1);
```